# Opening pipe connection to a file descriptor in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke, file-descriptor

I have a legacy app where it reads message from a client program from file descriptor 3. This is an external app so I cannot change this. The client is written in C#. How can we open a connection to a specific file descriptor in C#? Can we use something like AnonymousPipeClientStream()? But how do we specify the file descriptor to connect to?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to do that without P/Invoking to the native Windows API first.

First, you will need to open your file descriptor with a native P/Invoke call. This is done by the OpenFileById WINAPI function. [Here's how to use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365432(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN, [here's an other link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowssearch/thread/4b71fcb3-bea9-4cfb-bdb7-2f1a91522ea6/) explaining it in detail on the MSDN forums, and [here's some help (pinvoke.net)](http://www.pinvoke.net/) on how to construct your P/Invoke call.

Once you got the file handle, you need to wrap it in a SafeFileHandle, this time in safe, managed C#:

```
// nativeHandle is the WINAPI handle you have acquired with the P/Invoke call
SafeFileHandle safeHandle = new SafeFileHandle(nativeHandle, true);
```

Now you can open the file stream directly:

```
Stream stream = new FileStream(safeHandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

And from this point you can use it as any other file or stream in C#. Don't forget to dispose your objects once you're done.

Comment: Are these file ids the same as the C runtime file descriptors? Also, OpenByFileId is only supported on Vista or later.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the same issue by using [`_get_osfhandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks2530z6.aspx). Example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Comm : IDisposable
{
    [DllImport("MSVCRT.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    extern static IntPtr _get_osfhandle(int fd);

    public readonly Stream Stream;

    public Comm(int fd)
    {
        var handle = _get_osfhandle(fd);
        if (handle == IntPtr.Zero || handle == (IntPtr)(-1) || handle == (IntPtr)(-2))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("invalid handle");
        }

        var fileHandle = new SafeFileHandle(handle, true);
        Stream = new FileStream(fileHandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Stream.Dispose();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Hey Tim, I'm trying to use your code trying to generate a handle for FD3, and _get_osfhandle returns -1, Rings a bell?

Comment: @hardkoded: It doesn't, no.  I would suggest using `SetLastError = True` on the `DllImport` to see what the underlying error is.

Comment: `_get_osfhandle` is part of the Universal CRT, not the Windows API. It doesn't set the calling thread's last error code. Asking the CLR to preserve it for you will have it preserve a meaningless value.