# Cross-platform IPC communication between Node and .NET Core using File Descriptor / Pipe

Tags: linux, winapi, .net-core, pipe, ipc

I have a third-party Node application that uses pipes between its child process and the parent process for communication. It uses the `subprocess.stdio[3]` and `subprocess.stdio[4]` file descriptors, instead of standard input and standard output. Relevant docs: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocessstdio

I created a .NET Core application, which launched as the Node app's child process. The communication works fine on Windows. It's based on the following code from [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43494635/3145949):

```
internal class Comm : IDisposable
{
    [DllImport("MSVCRT.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern IntPtr _get_osfhandle(int fd);

    public readonly Stream Stream;

    public Comm(int fd)
    {
        var handle = _get_osfhandle(fd);
        if (handle == IntPtr.Zero || handle == (IntPtr)(-1) || handle == (IntPtr)(-2))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("invalid handle");
        }

        var fileHandle = new SafeFileHandle(handle, true);
        Stream = new FileStream(fileHandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Stream.Dispose();
    }       
}
```

Since this code is based on `_get_osfhandle` from MSVCRT.DLL, how can I make this class cross-platform so it works on both Windows, Linux, and macOS? What function should I import instead of `_get_osfhandle`?